# Missing Microsoft time zones

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

I'm looking at using the [Microsoft time zones](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/973627/microsoft-time-zone-index-values) (by utilising the [System.TimeZoneInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class in C#) to convert stored UTC dates to local timezone dates and vice versa.

However, I've noticed that this isn't a comprehensive list. For example, it currently only has one timezone defined for Greenland (`Greenland Standard Time (GMT-03:00) Greenland`), where [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Denmark#East_Greenland_Time) and [timeanddate](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/greenland) both show there are 2 major time zones in use (eastern and western) as well as 2 lesser used ones.

Is there a comprehensive list anywhere of missing timezones?

Comment: Windows time zone handling is actually quite bad. If it's not working for you, you can try https://nodatime.org.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The conversion data between Windows time zone IDs and [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) time zone IDs is available via [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org).

Looking at the data (and at the [raw IANA data in Github](https://github.com/eggert/tz)) it looks like the IANA time zones in question are:

- "America/Godthab" (West Greenland)
- "America/Scoresbysund" (East Greenland)

Those have corresponding Windows time zone IDs of:

- "Greenland Standard Time" (West Greenland)
- "Azores Standard Time" (um, not really East Greenland - read on)

Obviously the Azores and East Greenland are quite a long way apart - but it turns out they follow the same time zone rules, which is presumably why Microsoft has lumped them under a single time zone.

Basically, if you want to find the time in East Greenland for "America/Scoresbysund", then "Azores Standard Time" is your closest bet.

Comment: The CLDR mappings (version 34) are under `common/supplemental/windowsZones` for those trawling through the zip-file!